# iOS 7: Subclassed UINavigationbar crashing -layoutSubViews needs to call super

Tags: ios7, autolayout

## Update (23/02/2015)

Don't do what I am trying to do below. See the updated 'answer' underneath this question.

I am trying to implement a custom UINavigationBar in my project and use Autolayout to place an image and a textfield inside it.

I have subclassed the UINavigationBar, added my UIImageView with image and a UITextField and attempted to lay it out using AutoLayout, which works fine for iOS 8 but it keeps crashing on iOS 7.

Here is the code for the subclassed UINavigationBar

```
#import "SHNavigationBar.h"
#import "UIColor+SHColor.h"
#import "UIView+AutoLayout.h"
#import "UITextField+SHTextField.h"

@interface SHNavigationBar()
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *titleImage;
@end

@implementation SHNavigationBar

@synthesize searchTextField;
@synthesize titleImage;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if(self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        [self setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack];
        [self setTranslucent:NO];
        
        /**
         *   autoLayoutView below is a category that calls 
         *   setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints and sets it
         *   to NO for a view. 
         */
        self.titleImage = [UIImageView autoLayoutView];
        [self.titleImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Shelfd"]];
        [self.titleImage setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
        [self addSubview:self.titleImage];
    
        [self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.titleImage attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0 constant:10.0f]];
    
        [self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.titleImage attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:1.0 constant:0]];
    
    
    }
    return self;
}

/**
 *  This does not seem to work
 */
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
}
```

I am setting this subclassed UINavigationBar to my navigation controller with the following code

```
self.featuredNavigationController = [[FeaturedNavigationController alloc] initWithNavigationBarClass:[SHNavigationBar class] toolbarClass:[UIToolbar class]];
[self.featuredNavigationController.tabBarItem setTitle:@"Featured"];
```

On iOS 7, the error message I am getting is as follows:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Auto Layout still required after executing -layoutSubviews. SHNavigationBar's implementation of -layoutSubviews needs to call super.'
```

From this message, I tried adding the layoutSubviews function within my custom UINavigationBar class, but it doesn't work and I get the same error message as before.

Has anyone else encountered this problem and if so, how did you solve it?

Thanks

Comment: This is not necessarily an answer but more of an observation. Given that there is little or no discussion anywhere about using AutoLayout for UINavigationBars, it looks like this problem is unsolvable. I am starting to think the approach taken above is not necessarily the correct approach, since I have not seen it discussed anywhere else and cannot find the answer anywhere at all, despite more than 24 hours of trawling the internet trying to find a solution. I believe there is a better solution than using Frame based calculations - there must be - especially given AutoLayout is here to stay.

Comment: I will be taking a different approach to this problem and will document everything I have done, in the hope it helps others who have encountered this problem. The advice I have read thus far is to stay away from messing with the sub views inside a UINavigation bar altogether.

Answer (score 0):

While strictly speaking this answer is not a solution, I am hoping it will help anyone else who has encountered this issue.

From more discussion and research into a solution, I can confirm that using Autolayout on the subviews within A UINavigationBar is not good practice and attempting to do this will lead you down a rabbit hole, where more problems could arise in the future.

My advise is not to try to do this, because subsequent releases of iOS could break your code.